# overcoming gmails attachment blocking

Tags: c#, .net

I have sent some rar-red executable to someone via gmail and I can now not even download my own attachment. I am getting:

```
Anti-virus warning - 1 attachment contains a virus or blocked file. Downloading this attachment is disabled.
```

I found [this](http://spapas.github.io/2014/10/23/retrieve-gmail-blocked-attachments/) and try to implement the same in C#:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var encodedString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\original.txt");
    var decodedString = Base64Decode(encodedString);
    var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("d:\\result.rar");
    file.WriteLine(decodedString);

    file.Close();
}

public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
{
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Unfortunately, the resulting rar file can not be unrared (D:\result.rar: Unexpected end of archive). Is there something wrong with the way I decode the data? I am also not hundred percent sure which data to put into original.txt.

My original sent email looks something like this (where ... indicates not shown data to keep this post short):

```
...
--047d7b2e141ddd6f7e04ff5a46b7--
--047d7b2e141ddd6fd404ff5a46b9
Content-Type: application/rar; name="Bla.rar"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Bla.rar"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Attachment-Id: f_hy7mvnnm0

UmFyIRoHAM+QcwAADQAAAAAAAADyjXSAgCsAPD8BAO9bCQACZPAbLMVLsj4dMwsAIAAAAHhtbDJi
aWIuZXhlGAHRGQyJJhwSInMkmEkCQzAZBw4pgMAgIjAeMOKyLMXBZNYoQDUBBQRHiIjmHB05MkUx
...
cjR8qjjxbcI0s1b0SW86worLTu1860ysaZspuo8IlJZtnBtamJHLdGdp9YTcfkhsrnCba4l8o3oN
RiJTNE614Lb7GdfvySstNFD1eyVx1gexl8lax6hwn/8gxD17AEAHAA==
--047d7b2e141ddd6fd404ff5a46b9--
```

I have used this as my data:

```
UmFyIRoHAM+QcwAADQAAAAAAAADyjXSAgCsAPD8BAO9bCQACZPAbLMVLsj4dMwsAIAAAAHhtbDJi
aWIuZXhlGAHRGQyJJhwSInMkmEkCQzAZBw4pgMAgIjAeMOKyLMXBZNYoQDUBBQRHiIjmHB05MkUx
...
cjR8qjjxbcI0s1b0SW86worLTu1860ysaZspuo8IlJZtnBtamJHLdGdp9YTcfkhsrnCba4l8o3oN
RiJTNE614Lb7GdfvySstNFD1eyVx1gexl8lax6hwn/8gxD17AEAHAA==
```

Is this correct?

PS:

The data I have chosen is correct and I have answered my question. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Comment: If you vote down say why ... imho there is nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var encodedString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\original.txt");
        var bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("d:\\result.rar", bytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the document using the Gmail App on an Android Device.  Then connect the device to you laptop to transfer the files from the Android Device to your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The DecodeWithString() taken form [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does the trick. Hope this will help someone in the future.

PS:

This is the code:

```
public void DecodeWithString() {
   System.IO.StreamReader inFile;    
   string base64String;

   try {
      char[] base64CharArray;
      inFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\original.txt",
                              System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
      base64CharArray = new char[inFile.BaseStream.Length];
      inFile.Read(base64CharArray, 0, (int)inFile.BaseStream.Length);
      base64String = new string(base64CharArray);
   }
   catch (System.Exception exp) {
      // Error creating stream or reading from it.
      System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", exp.Message);
      return;
   }

   // Convert the Base64 UUEncoded input into binary output. 
   byte[] binaryData;
   try {
      binaryData = 
         System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
   }
   catch (System.ArgumentNullException) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Base 64 string is null.");
      return;
   }
   catch (System.FormatException) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Base 64 string length is not " +
         "4 or is not an even multiple of 4." );
      return;
   }

   // Write out the decoded data.
   System.IO.FileStream outFile;
   try {
      outFile = new System.IO.FileStream("d:\\result.rar",
                                 System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                                 System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
      outFile.Write(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
      outFile.Close();
   }
   catch (System.Exception exp) {
      // Error creating stream or writing to it.
      System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", exp.Message);
   }
}
```